# hibernate.cfg.xml Invalid system identifier: http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd

Tags: hibernate

I want to work with Hibernate with XML configuration file.

This it hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run my application I get the error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier:
>   http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd  at
>   sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider$Resolver.resolveEntity(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:997)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1151)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.getLoadingDoc(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:106)
>     at
>   sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:78)
>     ... 29 more

Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration), the Hibernate Configuration XML should start with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
```

That can be a cause for the error you're facing.